# Why the Vec3b can't be initialized as an array?

Tags: c++, opencv

I wanted to try that

```
Vec3b colorsense = {
            map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_up(1)),
            map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_down(1)),
            map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_left(1)),
            map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_right(1)),
            map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_upright(1)),
            map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_upleft(1)),
            map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_downright(1)),
            map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_downleft(1))};
```

can be usable, but after testing it, I don
t think that it work. oh and the function trace.move_up are all points in the matrix map

This is my entire main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "Trace.h"

// Macros
#define log(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;

#define error(x) std::cerr << x << std::endl;

// using namespaces:
//using namespace cv;
//using namespace std;

// enum;
enum {up = 0, down = 1, left = 2, right = 3, upright = 4, upleft = 5, downright = 6, downleft = 7};

// Main function;
int main() {
    try {
        int x = 0,movement;
        Trace trace(0, 0);
        Mat map = imread("tmp.bmp"), edges;
        resize(map, map, {1028, 672}, 0, 0, INTER_NEAREST_EXACT);
        std::vector<Vec3b> colorsense = {
                map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_up(1)),
                map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_down(1)),
                map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_left(1)),
                map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_right(1)),
                map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_upright(1)),
                map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_upleft(1)),
                map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_downright(1)),
                map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_downleft(1))};

        switch (movement) {
            case up:
                colorsense[up];
                break;
            case down:
                colorsense[down];
                break;
            case left:
                colorsense[left];
                break;
            case right:
                colorsense[right];
                break;
            case upright:
                colorsense[upright];
                break;
            case upleft:
                colorsense[upleft];
                break;
            case downright:
                colorsense[downright];
                break;
            case downleft:
                colorsense[downleft];
                break;
            default:
                movement = right;
                break;
        }
       for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            trace.draw(map, 255, 0, 0, 1);
           if(colorsense[right][0]== 255 || colorsense[right][1]== 255 || colorsense[right][2]== 255){
               trace.move_downright(0);
           } else {
               trace.move_right(0);
           }
            namedWindow("map");
            imshow("map", map);
            waitKey(10);
    }


      //  Canny(map,edges,100,100,3,false);
      //  Laplacian(map,map, CV_64F);
        log(map.rows);
        log(map.cols);
        if (map.empty()) {
            error("Could not load image");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        namedWindow("map");
        imshow("map", map);
        waitKey();
       log("Hello World");
    }
    catch(const char* msg){
        error(msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The for loop you guys see here is the loop that draws the line. But with the function i wrote, it won't be able to change direction when the black objects is close.

But when i write the if statement similar like this

```
map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_up(1))[0]
map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_up(1))[1]
map.at<Vec3b>(trace.move_up(1))[2]
```

Then it works..., why?

Comment: [mcve] and compiler error in the question please

Comment: right, left are enums

Comment: i don't think that is a compile error, i can run the code just fine, but it won't make a different action in the if statemens

Comment: if its not a compiler error, then please explain what the code is supposed to do and what it does instead

Comment: you have a simple image with white background and black boxes, and you trace a line. when that line touches the black objects, it changes the direction.